# Correction for multiple testing for very large files with repetitions

Tags: r, python-3.x, statistics, large-files

I have 10 files with size ~8-9 Gb like:

```
7       72603   0.0780181622612
15      72603   0.027069072329
20      72603   0.00215643186987
24      72603   0.00247965378216
29      72603   0.0785606184492
32      72603   0.0486866833899
33      72603   0.000123332654879
```

For each pair of numbers (1st and 2nd column) I have p-value (3rd column). 
However, I have repeated pairs (they can be in different files) and I want to get rid of one of them. If the files were smaller, I would use pandas. E.g.:

```
7    15    0.0012423442
...
15   7     0.0012423442
```

Also I want to apply to this set a correction for multiple testing, but the vector of values is very large.

Is it possible to do this with Python or R?

Comment: If your files dont't fit into your RAM, you will probably need to store them in a database or filesystem-based datastructures. Maybe the R-packages `ff`, `sqldf` or `RSQLite` can help. Also look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969547/sorting-and-removing-duplicates-in-a-ffdf-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 1):

```
> df <- data.frame(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
+                  V2 = c("B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
+                  n = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2))
> df
  V1 V2 n
1  A  B 1
2  A  C 3
3  B  A 1
4  B  C 2
5  C  A 3
6  C  B 2
> df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]
  V1 V2 n
1  A  B 1
2  A  C 3
4  B  C 2
```

Comment: Depending on the RAM available to the original poster this is useful or not at all useful.